# Reading a file in to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am new to php. I have a text file which contains text something like this

```
<??blah blahh blah
   blah blah blah
   .......
??>

<??blah blahh blah
   blah blah blah
   .......
??>

<??blah blahh blah
   blah blah blah
   ...... .
??>
```

It means My main data is in between `<?? and ??>` I want to make an array which will contains all main data in array (removing these `<?? & ??>` charachter). So that I can insert the data items in MySql table. I don't know how to make an array from file lile this.

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: @nickb As I said i am very new to php. I have never used it. But today need to make some webservices for my application.So first i need nysql database and this main data in table. I just know some basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with explode and a little bit of creativity, like so:

```
$str = file_get_contents( 'yourfile.txt');
$array = explode( '<??', $str);
array_shift( $array); // first element is empty
array_walk( $array, function( &$el) { $el = str_replace( '??>', '', $el); });
var_dump( $array);
```

Now, your array looks something like:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(52) "blah blahh blah
   blah blah blah
   .......


"
  [1]=>
  string(52) "blah blahh blah
   blah blah blah
   .......


"
  [2]=>
  string(49) "blah blahh blah
   blah blah blah
   ...... .
"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this will be of assistance.

First off, you'll need to look into the file library associated with PHP.

**Reference**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Using fopen and fread, you can open up the file in question and parse it from there.

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Next, we'll use some simple string manipulation to get your important information. Using `split`, we can cut up your file contents into the good stuff.

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

```
<?php
// sanitize content headers
$contents = split("<\?\?", $contents);
foreach($contents as $content) {
   // remove content footers
   str_replace("??>", "", $content);
}
?>
```

Lastly, we'll go through all the elements in the array we've just created using split and insert them into our database.

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

```
<?php
// sanitize content headers
$contents = split("<\?\?", $contents);
foreach($contents as $content) {
   if (empty($content)) {
       continue;
   }
   // remove content footers
   str_replace("??>", "", $content);

   // insert into database
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `something` VALUES ('" . $content . "')");
}
?>
```

Overall, the final code should look something like this:

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

// sanitize content headers
$contents = split("<\?\?", $contents);
foreach($contents as $content) {
   if (empty($content)) {
       continue;
   }
   // remove content footers
   str_replace("??>", "", $content);

   // insert into database
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `something` VALUES ('" . $content . "')");
}
?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting an error `Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated `

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php    
preg_match_all("/(?:<\?\?)(.+?)(?:\?\?>)/sm",file_get_contents("test.txt"),$result);
print_r($result[1]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<?php

$filestring = file_get_contents('YOUR_FILE_TO_PARSE');
$pattern = '/<\?\?[\w\s.]*\?\?>/';
preg_match($pattern, $filestring, $matches);

?>
```

where $matches will be your array

Comment: This is a much more efficient way of handling this than explode or split